# How connect inputs with another selector in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to change `<p>` color by checking one of the buttons:

```html
<div class="textstyle">
    <span class="textarea">
        <p class="text">Some text here</p>
    </span>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="textbutton" checked/><label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="textbutton"/><label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" id="green" name="textbutton"/><label for="green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, buttons and paragraph have one grandparent. How can I change this structure or what CSS rules should I add to make this work?

UPD: without JS or jQuery

Comment: Maybe a basic css tutorial is helpful to you: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/

Comment: I think this is sort of what you want, without javascript and jquery: https://codepen.io/tobiasdev/pen/YWpBxX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way you can achieve this with HTML/CSS only.

`input ~ p` Selects every `<p>` element that are preceded by a `<input>` element.

`input:checked` Selects every checked `<input>` element. In our case, we are using radio buttons so we can only select on at a time.

```css
input#red:checked ~ .text {
color: red;
}
input#blue:checked ~ .text {
color: blue;
}
input#green:checked ~ .text {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="textstyle">
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="textbutton" checked/><label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="textbutton"/><label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" id="green" name="textbutton"/><label for="green">Green</label>
         <p class="text">Some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I leave the ```<span>``` wrapper around ```<p>```?

Comment: Hi @Watermelonnn, yes you can have `<span>` wrapper around `<p>` but in this case, you need to tweak your `CSS` a bit. For example: `input#red:checked ~ span .text`

Answer (score 1):

Considering your original html structures, no way to get parent `div` element of `input`, and relative `p.text` element with pure css, now.

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?answertab=active#tab-top)

Using Javascript approach!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how and if this can be done with CSS only **without altering the original HTML structure** but here's an approach with Javascript:

```js
//selects the paragraph tag
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p.text');
//selects all radio inputs
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

//adds a click event listener to each radio input which will trigger a change of the paragraph style property which matches the radio buton id (ex. red text color after clicking the radio input with id=red).
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    paragraph.style.color = e.target.id;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="textstyle">
    <span class="textarea">
        <p class="text">Some text here</p>
    </span>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="textbutton"/><label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="textbutton"/><label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" id="green" name="textbutton"/><label for="green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this codes maybe help you :

```js
$('input[name="textbutton"]').on('change' , function(){
var _color = $(this).attr('id');
$('.text').addClass(_color);
});
```

and according to p element class name you can give style to your element

Comment: What's the point of using jQuery instead of vanilla Javascript?